# nginx does not set remote clients ip address

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I want to get the IP address of the client that visits my page. My app is running behind a proxy so I set this configuration to my nginx file:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Now I try to get the IP address like this in express

```
req.ip
req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]
req.ips
req.connection.remoteAdress
```

Nothing seems to work. I also set trust proxy to true

```
app.set("trust proxy", true);
```

But the other configuration like `proxy_set_header Host` or `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"` are working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was that i have 2 applications running behind my proxy and i set the configuration on the wrong proxy.

I had to scroll down.